# Sql Server 2005, deleting and renumbering

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am pretty new to sql so plz excuse me if this is a noobish query.

[image: http://i247.photobucket.com/albums/gg149/izzner/Clipboard01-1.jpg]

As seen from the above picture i have some data in Sql DB table
now i need to delete every 4th row starting from a serial number i specify and then the Serial_no column needs to be renumbered without changing the order of rows.

i need all this to be accomplished by a single query if possible, but am struggling since last 2 days

Hope you all can help me.
Thanks in advance

```
//USING THIS CODE TO DELETE every 4th row// 
    DELETE 
            FROM Tbl2
            FROM 
            Tbl2 AS A 
            INNER JOIN
            (
              SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GETDATE()) AS CNT , *
              FROM Tbl2
            ) AS B ON A.Serial_no = B.Serial_no
            WHERE CNT%4 = 0 AND CNT >= 10
```

However the renumbering query (below)

```
DECLARE @FIRSTID INT = 1000000010

UPDATE tbl2
SET Serial_no = @FIRSTID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Serial_no) - 1
FROM tbl2
```

throws an error
"Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."

Comment: It would be better if you could eliminate this requirement - having serial numbers that change is usually a bad sign. Why do you need to eliminate the gaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it easily by join query. do something like

```
        DELETE 
        FROM tbl2
        FROM 
        tbl2 AS A 
        INNER JOIN
        (
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GETDATE()) AS CNT , *
          FROM tbl2
        ) AS B ON A.serial_no = B.serial_no
        WHERE CNT%4 = 0 AND CNT >= 10
```

For re-arranging the serial number use something like following query :

```
        DECLARE @FIRSTID INT = 1000000001

        UPDATE tbl2
        SET serialno = @FIRSTID + ROW - 1
        FROM 
        tbl2 as a 
        inner join
        (
        SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY serial_no) AS ROW
        FROM tbl2
        ) AS b on a.serial_no = b.serial_no
```

Comment: what does  A.ID = B.ID stand for?

Comment: This query doesn't address the second part of the requirement: `then the Serial_no column needs to be renumbered without changing the order of rows.`

Comment: ok it stands for column name.. how silly of me :P, But how do i make the query to start deleting from serial number 10 instead of the fist serial number

Comment: @Hiren Dhaduk The query seems to be working great now the only thing left to do is specifying the starting serial number for the delete operation and then renumbering. How do we take care of that??

Comment: i am modifying that query give me 5 to 10 min .

Comment: @Hiren Dhaduk your first query did the job of both deleting every 4th row and also renumbering, However your latest query/update doesnt seem to delete any rows :(. i just need to somehow specify the serial no from where to start deleting in yours first query

Comment: renumbering query throws an error "Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."

Comment: there may be problem with your query . I checked it here . can you give me your query ? .

Comment: please check my original post, i have updated the query there.

Comment: if you want to give starting number then remove query use only DECLARE @FIRSTID INT = 1000000010 . remove query which set the firstID

Comment: still the same error..renumbering query throws an error "Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses. I have edited my first post with the latest query

Comment: well 1 + ROW -1 makes all serial_no = 1.. :( , BTW as regards to your efforts I dont mind paying you for helping me out..:)

Comment: i am uploading a scaled down backup of my database(its just 18MB) on mediafire so that u can test the query ...

Comment: ok download from here http://www.mediafire.com/download/77mrr9qpyki4v6m/Gate.bak     Table name = tbl2

Comment: I don't have sql 2005 installed in my machine . can you test my updated query ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this stored procedure might work, I haven't tested it fully though and it lacks error handling etc. The first part removes every 4th row and the cursor updates the serial numbers. You call it using `EXEC usp_update_serials 10000010` for example:

```
DROP PROC usp_update_serials 
GO
CREATE PROC usp_update_serials @serial INT AS 
-- delete every fourth row
WITH cte AS (
SELECT serial_no, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY serial_no) -1 AS rank
   FROM table1 t WHERE serial_no >= @serial
   )
DELETE cte WHERE rank%4 = 0 

-- update serial numbers
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @serial_no int, @rank int, @prev int

DECLARE serial_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT serial_no, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY serial_no) AS rank
FROM table1 t 
OPEN serial_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM serial_cursor 
INTO @serial_no, @rank

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SELECT @prev = t.serial_no FROM (SELECT serial_no, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY serial_no) AS rank
FROM TABLE1) t WHERE t.rank = @rank - 1

IF @serial_no != @prev
    BEGIN       
        UPDATE table1 SET serial_no = @prev+1 WHERE serial_no= @serial_no
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM serial_cursor 
    INTO @serial_no, @rank
END 
CLOSE serial_cursor
DEALLOCATE serial_cursor
```

Obviously this is just a rough idea and shouldn't be used in production...

Comment: I ran your procedure but it seems to be getting stuck with the first serial no i specify. "Sql management studio is showing "Executing Query" since last 10 mins...

Comment: Like I said, I haven't tested it much as I lack appropriate data. Is the serial_no column `INT`? I assumed it is, but this won't work if it's a `CHAR` or any other type. And I assume you changed the appropriate table names to reflect their real names.

Comment: Anyway cursors are often a suboptimal solution. The update query provided in Hirens answers would be better.

Comment: your procedure works file if there are say about 500 rows..However when i run it on my 50000+ rows it gets stuck. i have changed my serial_no column to int

Comment: Cursors can be really slow. I suggest you disregard my answer and use the one provided by Hiren Dhaduk instead.